# AWS Redshift Disaster Recovery - Is it possible to restore tables in another account to cluster provisioned by IAC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, backup-strategies

Setting AWS Redshift disaster recovery plan. Ideally I would like to have the ability to restore table data to a new cluster (provisioned by IAC) in my DR account.

Sharing snapshots with the DR account I don't believe will work as restoring tables needs to take place within the cluster the snapshots were created from.

Restoring snapshots to a new provisioned cluster isn't ideal as that cluster creation takes place outside of our IAC.

I believe my only other option would be to use the COPY/ UNLOAD sql commands?

Comment: Can I ask... Why do you have a "DR account"? I can understand putting resources in different AZs or Regions in case of physical disaster, or even backing up data to a different account to prevent accidental/intentional deletion, but it is a little unusual to have a different AWS Account for disaster 'recovery'. It would be much easier to restore services into the same AWS Account, which is a billing/security/ownership partition rather than a physically separate entity.

Comment: You could restore the entire snapshot to a new Redshift cluster and then extract desired data. The fact that it is outside your 'Infrastructure as Code' would normally be permissible because it is 'emergency response' rather than 'business as usual'.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I agree it makes sense to keep everything in one account, unfortunately I'm working within requirements. I've ultimately I ended up working with our data lake team to come up with a solution. Raw data will be exported to s3 and replicated to our DR account.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your Redshift cluster [automatically backed up to a second AWS Region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-snapshots.html#cross-region-snapshot-copy). In case of failover to the second Region, you can restore the Redshift cluster there

If your IaC is CloudFormation, you can then [bring the newly restored cluster into your IaC stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html)